# Flink+Kafka 0.10: How to create a Table with the Kafka message timestamp as field?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to extract the timestamp of the messages that are produced by `FlinkKafkaConsumer010` as values in the data stream.

I am aware of the `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` class, but this seems to only extract the timestamp for the purposes of time aggregates via the `DataStream` API.

I would like to make that Kafka message timestamp available in a `Table` so later on, I can use SQL on it.

**EDIT**:  Tried this:

```
  val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010("test", new SimpleStringSchema, properties)
  consumer.setStartFromEarliest()

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val tenv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)

  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

  class KafkaAssigner[T] extends AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks[T] {
    var maxTs = 0L
    override def extractTimestamp(element: T, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
      maxTs = Math.max(maxTs, previousElementTimestamp)
      previousElementTimestamp
    }
    override def getCurrentWatermark: Watermark = new Watermark(maxTs - 1L)
  }

  val stream = env
    .addSource(consumer)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new KafkaAssigner[String])
    .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))

  val tbl = tenv.fromDataStream(stream, 'w, 'ts.rowtime)
```

It compiles, but throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Field reference expression requested.
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment$$anonfun$1.apply(TableEnvironment.scala:630)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment$$anonfun$1.apply(TableEnvironment.scala:624)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.getFieldInfo(TableEnvironment.scala:624)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.registerDataStreamInternal(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:398)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.StreamTableEnvironment.fromDataStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:85)
```

at the very last line of the above code.

**EDIT2**: Thanks to @fabian-hueske for pointing me to a workaround.  Full code at https://github.com/andrey-savov/flink-kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's Kafka 0.10 consumer automatically sets the timestamp of a Kafka message as the event-time timestamp of produced records if the time characteristic EventTime is configured (see [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html#using-kafka-timestamps-and-flink-event-time-in-kafka-010)).

After you have ingested the Kafka topic into a `DataStream` with timestamps (still not visible) and watermarks assigned, you can convert it into a `Table` with the `StreamTableEnvironment.fromDataStream(stream, fieldExpr*)` method. The `fieldExpr*` parameter is a list of expressions that describe the schema of the generated table. You can add a field that holds the record timestamp of the stream with an expression `mytime.rowtime`, where `mytime` is the name of the new field and `rowtime` indicates that the value is extracted from the record timestamp. Please check the [docs for details](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/streaming.html#during-datastream-to-table-conversion-1).

**NOTE:** As @bfair pointed out, the conversion of a `DataStream` of an atomic type (such as `DataStream[String]`) fails with an exception in Flink 1.3.2 and earlier versions. The bug has been reported as [FLINK-7939](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7939) and will be fixed in the next versions.

Comment: Hi @fabian, thanks for answering.   I followed the Scala example from the link you had, but facing a runtime exception (Flink 1.3.2) when I try to register the `.rowtime` as `fieldExpr`.   Updated the question with an example.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the code and you hit a bug that is related to the type of the DataStream. DataStreams with atomic types (single values such as String in your case) are internally handled with a separate code path. If you add a MapFunction to wrap the String in a tuple (`Tuple1[String]`), it should work as expected.

Comment: It would be great to post a reference to the bug here so others can trace it when it gets resolved.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the bug report. I have a patch for the bug ready and will open a pull request soon. Thanks!